# jQuery addClass/removeClass transition not smooth but stuttering

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, transition, addclass

In a picture gallery I try to make all pictures not hovered greyscale:

```
$('.featured_product_item').mouseover(function() {

    $('.featured_product_item').not(this).addClass('greyscale',200);

});

$('.featured_product_item').mouseout(function() {

    $('.featured_product_item').removeClass('greyscale',200);

});
```

However, it is not smooth if you move your mouse to another item before the first animation has finished... how could you achieve that in a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()`.

http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/

The `mouseenter` event will only fire when the mouse changes from being **outside** of the element to **inside** the element.  The opposite is true for `mouseleave`.

This way you should not see the stuttering behavior as seen with `mouseover` because every time the mouse shifts and you are **over** the element, the event will fire.

Answer (score 0):

Something to the effect of this using stop

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  
    $(".featured_product_item").mouseover(function () {
        $('.featured_product_item').not(this).stop(true,true).addClass("selected", 1000);
    });
  
    $(".featured_product_item").mouseout(function () {
        $('.featured_product_item').stop(true,true).removeClass("selected",1000);
    });
  
});​
```

Please check the jQuery Manual for [stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XqGUm/) for this

**NOTE**

Im not sure you are using addClass and removeClass correctly.  I have not found any reference in the manual of using an animation time for the second param.  From the manual:

> .addClass( function(index, currentClass) )
>
> **function(index, currentClass)** A function returning one or more space-separated class names to be added to the existing class name(s). Receives the index position of the element in the set and the existing class name(s) as arguments. Within the function, this refers to the current element in the set.

**UPDATE**

I had some code in the wrong place and missed the extra params for stop.  Please check the code above and the new [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XqGUm/2/).

Comment: it is possible to use addClass with UI core, see: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/addClass

You solution unfortunately makes the animation not even start, because you stop it right away...

Comment: I see what you are looking for now.... give me a few and I will come up with something for you to look at